# Creating First Spring(no spring boot) web project with no jsp(html only), but getting 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build my first spring web project, but i don't want to use jsp. All i want to use is rest controller, but i was unable to pass even the first request("/") which uses welcome file index.html(index.jsp by default). 
I am going to paste my folder structure and classes.

This is my app config class

```
package com.abs.sstest.security;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "index.html");
}

public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
}
```

This is my Init class

```
package com.abs.sstest.security;

public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
}

private void registerDispatcherServlet(final ServletContext servletContext) {
    WebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = createContext(AppConfig.class);
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext);
    Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

private WebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(annotatedClasses);
    return context;
}

}
```

This is my securityconfig class

```
package com.abs.sstest.security;

 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
    .and().formLogin()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

}

}
```

This is my security init

```
package com.abs.sstest.security;


public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends 
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

This is my folder structure Folder structure

[image]

I have pasted index.html inside multiple folder because i got confused reading various forums.

Edit:
Now i changed my app conifg class

```
package com.abs.sstest.security;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abs.sstest")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
 public void    configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) { 
        configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/index");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/login2", "/login2");
}

public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/views/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/");
}
}
```

The init class is now much more simpler

```
package com.websystique.springsecurity.configuration;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

And now main thing all my html files are in src/main/webapp/index.html

But this resulted in a new problem, now i have to return even extension from controller.
For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    return "login.html";//login doesn't work
}
```

Comment: A non-web.xml webapp requires a servlet 3.0 container. Please add the server's output-log.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should put index.html in /WEB_INF/view/.
It seems that you need to add ViewResolver so spring knows how to parse returned string from controller. So try to add to your AppConfig class:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".html");
    return bean;
}
```

Of course make sure there are needed dependencies in your pom file!